# Use soundcard native rates only in alsa

Tags: alsa

Have ubuntustdio latest rolling release and a audigy rx soundcard. I disabled pulseaudio and setup alsa to use hw:0,0. Whenever I test this with speaker-test, no matter the rate I choose, even invented rates, the requested rate apparently is used natively. This can't be right. So either alsa or something else is converting to something, dont know to what or how to check. aplay -l says whatever rate was requested was also granted. What can i do to completely turn off any resampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Audigy RX has an internal resampler, so as far as the driver is concerned, the hardware indeed supports all sample rates.

The default target sample rate is 48 kHz. If you want to prevent applications from using any other rate, add this device to `/etc/asound.conf` or your `~/.asoundrc`:

```perl
pcm.only48k {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
    rate 48000
}

pcm.!default = only48k
```

Comment: Sorry to say after persisting for two years trying to get new hardware (gpus/soundcards) to work, linux has been a waste of time and money. None of the sound systems in linux alsa/oss4/pulse support my cards native sampling rates above 48khz 16 bit. Cant use stereo direct or any other feature of the card. Might as well be an sblive 2 value crap card that all drivers treat it as. zxr no drivers ever.

Comment: Creative does not publish information about their recent hardware. The only current PCI(e) sound cards with decent driver support are some Xonars, and those have simpler hardware.